# Unable to Google spreadsheet lastUpdateTime using Python gspread

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm using Google spreadsheets api with Python package `gspread`
I have given read permissions to a spreadsheet by adding service account to spreadsheet invite as viewer.

I'm able to read spreadsheet contents but not able to get `lastUpdateTime`

I'm seeing following exception,

```
gspread.exceptions.APIError:
{'errors':
[{'domain': 'usageLimits',
'reason': 'accessNotConfigured',
'message': 'Access Not Configured. Drive API has not been used in project <projct_num> before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting 
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/overview?project=<projct_num> then retry.
```

But I'm unable to find what exactly needs enabling.

Comment: Please edit your question include the code that is causing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Access Not Configured. Drive API has not been used in project

Means that you are using a method that requires access to the Google drive api. In order to use that method you need to enable that api in your project. You have probably already enabled the google sheets api you just need to enable drive api as well.

Go to google developer console as instructed under library and enable the google drive api. Wait a few minutes and try again.

Comment: I had only Sheets api enabled to start with. When I enabled the Drive API it is working as expected